# ReplaceAll isolated string correctly

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I'm working on a translator app and have ran into a small problem. For example:
when I `type` in `Hond`, I want the `output` to be `Dog`, and when i `type` in `Honderd`, I want the `output` to be `Hundred`. But instead i get `Dogerd` when i type in Hond. So it just takes the translation of Hond and adds the remaining letters. I came up with a solution by putting Honderd above Hond in my code. But there has to be another solution to this problem right? This is the code:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    mType = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.typeWordTxt);
    mSearch = (Button) findViewById(R.id.find8tn);
    mResults = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.resultsTxt);

    mSearch.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            String resultaat = mType.getText().toString().toLowerCase();
            resultaat = resultaat
                    //Getallen
                    .replaceAll("honderd", "hundred")
                    .replaceAll("hond", "dog")
            mResults.setText(resultaat);
```

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use `\\b` word boundary to isolate your word as single word instead matching it from some other word

`\\bhonderd\\b` and `\\bhond\\b`

```
    String s ="Honderd Honderd Hond".toLowerCase();
    System.out.println(s
            .replaceAll("\\bhond\\b", "dog")
            .replaceAll("\\bhonderd\\b", "hundred"));
```

Output:

```
hundred hundred dog
```

---

Demo

```js
const honderd_rep = /\bhonderd\b/g;
const hond_rep  = /\bhond\b/g;
const str = 'honderd honderd hond';
const result = str.replace(hond_rep,'dog').replace(honderd_rep, 'hundred');
console.log(result);
```

Comment: Thank you for the quick reply! I was looking for this and it works now!

Comment: @CFOJOLT i am glad that i could help , happy coding